# Freely transforming an image to correct perspective

Tags: c#, wpf

C# newbie here so please forgive me if my terminology isn't quite correct.

As part of this project, I have a user hold up a piece of paper to a webcam so I can capture, isolate and then eventually display back what they've drawn on it. I've put some restrictions on where the corners of the paper have to be in order for the program to accept it, but there's still the chance that it's distorted by perspective.

Here's an example image that I've captured and isolated the paper out of: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY4XB.jpg)

What I want to be able to do is to distort this image so that the corners of the piece of paper are turned back into a 8.5x11-proportioned rectangle (as if the user had scanned it rather than held it up to the webcam). Rotation and skewing can only get me so far, ideally I would be able to freely transform the image, like in Photoshop. I found [this example](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-distortion.php), I am basically trying to do the opposite. Curious if anyone's had to do this, before I start trying to reverse that four-point image distortion example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes called a Quadrilateral warp.

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft.

Our [DotImage Photo SDK](http://atalasoft.com/photofree) can do this and it's free. Look at QuadrilateralWarpCommand.  You need to know the source and destination quadrilateral.

Comment: Thanks Lou! Taking a look now.

Comment: This did it. In case anyone else comes across this, to get it to work I had to convert my project's target framework from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to .NET Framework 4 and then add a reference to System.Web.